# HTTP Sampler for PUT method does not work in SmartMeter

Tags: smartmeter

I'm using SmartMeter as a nice application for performance tests. Everything works great except PUT request via **et@sm - HTTP Request** - it sends an empty request body. I need to send some data in a PUT request body, but it doesn't work. My version of SmartMeter is 1.0.4.
Can you help me guys?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue has been fixed in recently released version 1.0.5, see [release notes](https://www.smartmeter.io/documentation#toc-v1-0-5--2015-09-09-) for more detail.